# laravel works on the php development server but on apache gives weird error

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider' not found
```

I'm using dingo api. It's weird because it was working normally but then suddenly it gives me this error. and the weirder part is that it works perfectly on the php development server `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` but with apache it gives me this error.

Comment: Do your folders has right access permissions?

Comment: What OS are you using? Linux, Windows?

Comment: I'm using fedora 23.
My permissions are mostly 755.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize. I was using the wrong url the whole time.

Answer (score 1):

either:

```
composer update
```

or comment the ServiceProvider out of:

```
app.php
```

And then composer update

Make sure JWT is inside of your composer file eg:

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*"
```

Edit:

This is assuming you are on a seperate server and are having issues, if not I am sorry :P

Comment: what do you mean "comment the ServiceProvider out of app.php"?

Comment: I see you found the answer, however: had you needed to composer update and the package didn't exist on the server you would have needed to comment the: Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class, out of app.php to get composer to install it :)

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you :))